# Special characters in bibliography with natbib

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to generate a bibliography using the package natbib.
Everything works fine if I use the style plainnat provided with natbib. But when I change the style file (for example [Ecology](https://sites.google.com/site/esalatex/files-for-download/ecology.bst?attredirects=0&d=1) or [APA](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/images/apa-good.bst.zip)) I get such log messages :

```
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 290 replaced by U+FFFD.
Missing character: There is no � in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text
```

And special characters like Å are disapearing.

I use Xelatex for compilation. Thanks for any help !

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
```

Sample of my .bib file
In this case the first letter of the surname of the first author

```
@article{ARRHENIUS_2004_PRE,
 title = {Predictability of the mixture toxicity of 12 similarly acting congeneric inhibitors of photosystem {II} in marine periphyton and epipsammon communities},
 volume = {68},
 url = {sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166445X04001298},
 number = {4},
 urldate = {2013-05-29},
 journal = {Aquatic Toxicology},
 author = {Arrhenius, Åsa and Grönvall, Frederick and Scholze, Martin and Backhaus, Thomas and Blanck, Hans},
 year = {2004},
 pages = {351–367}
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of a bib entry that causes the problem?

Comment: Please, add it to your question.

Comment: For strange reasons, `ö` survives, while `Å` doesn't. Use `{\AA}sa` for the name.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was wondering if there is a simple solution to this problem. But apparently not.

Comment: I tried using `bibtexu` instead of `bibtex`; there were some mysterious messages on the terminal, but the result seemed good. However it's an unmaintained program and I doubt it's really reliable.

Comment: Did you try biblatex with the `natbib=true` option, and use biber instead of bibtex? Biber understands utf8, so that your .bib file can be utf8-encoded.

Comment: I tried the suggestion of Bernard and it works! So I'm going to move to biblatex/biber. Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments